# Apache 2.4 reverse proxy produces wrong anchors

Tags: apache-2.4, reverse-proxy, httpd

I ran Apache 2.4.20 on AIX 6.1 as a reverse proxy in order to access Oracle Business Intelligence 11.1.1.7.150120 running on a backend Server.

The reverse proxy modifies the original HTML code resulting in HREF anchors set to the wrong place.

This leads to malfunctioning menus (the anchor is not on a table structure anymore).

Original HTML code (part):

```
<a 
    id="selEditDashboard"
    class="NQWMenuItem NQWMenuItemWIconMixin"
    href="javascript:void(null)"
    onclick="EditPage('saw.dll?EditDashboard&amp;PortalPath=%2fusers%2fweblogic%2f_portal&amp;Page=page%201&amp;Done=saw.dll%3fDashboard');return false;"
>

<table class="MenuItemTable" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
<tr>
<td class="MenuItemIconCell">
<img border="0" src="res/sk_FusionFX/catalog/edit_ena.png" alt="Dashboard bearbeiten"/>
</td>
<td class="MenuItemTextCell" colspan="2">Dashboard bearbeiten
</td>
</tr>
</table>
</a>
```

HTML code coming from reverse Proxy:

```
<a 
    id="selEditDashboard"
    class="NQWMenuItem NQWMenuItemWIconMixin"
    href="javascript:void(null)"
    onclick="EditPage('saw.dll?EditDashboard&amp;PortalPath=%2fusers%2fweblogic%2f_portal&amp;Page=page%201&amp;Done=saw.dll%3fDashboard');return false;"
>
</a>
<table class="MenuItemTable" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
<tr>
<td class="MenuItemIconCell">
<img border="0" src="res/sk_FusionFX/catalog/edit_ena.png" alt="Dashboard bearbeiten">
</td>
<td class="MenuItemTextCell" colspan="2">Dashboard bearbeiten
</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Here's an excerpt from my **httpd.conf**:

```
<IfModule proxy_module>
        LogLevel info
        SetOutputFilter INFLATE;proxy-html;DEFLATE
        SSLProxyEngine On

        ProxyPreserveHost On
        ProxyRequests Off

        ProxyHTMLEnable On
        RequestHeader unset Accept-Encoding
        ProxyHTMLCharsetOut *

        ProxyHTMLStripComments Off
        ProxyHTMLMeta On
        ProxyHTMLExtended On

        <Proxy *>
           Order deny,allow
           Allow from all
        </Proxy>

        ProxyPass          /oa-links.html http://backend_server_and_port/oa-links.html
        ProxyPassReverse   /oa-links.html http://backend_server_and_port/oa-links.html

        <Location />
        Order deny,allow
                Allow from all
        </Location>

        ProxyPass          /analytics/   http://backend_server_and_port/analytics/
        ProxyPassReverse   /analytics/   http://backend_server_and_port/analytics/
        <Location /analytics/>
                ProxyPassReverse /analytics/
                Order deny,allow
                Allow from all
        </Location>

        SetEnv proxy-sendchunked 1

        Header edit Location ^http://backend_server_and_port/analytics/ https://backend_server_and_port/analytics/
</IfModule>
```

**Please help!**

Answer (score 0):

From what I can tell `mod_proxy_html` only really understands HTML 4.01 and XHTML 1.0 based on https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_proxy_html.html#proxyhtmldoctype.

Searching whether a `<table>` is allowed within an `<a>` turns up https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6013943/table-tag-inside-anchor-tag amongst other answers which suggests that it's not allowed in HTML 4 so it's my hunch that `mod_proxy_html` is "helpfully" rewriting your document to be valid HTML 4 which is breaking your anchors.

Looking at https://httpd.apache.org/docs/trunk/mod/mod_proxy_html.html#proxyhtmldoctype suggests Apache >2.4 might have better smarts W.R.T. HTML 5 so you could try using a development release and see if that performs any better.